# Why doesn't obj.start() run when I run my code?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning java and practicing on sololearn.com and I copied one of the examples to practice typing code. However the code here -

```
//Create myClass
class Loader extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Hello Young World");
    }
}
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Loader obj = new Loader();
        obj.start();
    }
}
```

isn't printing "Hello Young World" to my console. In fact I had to add a 'main()' method to the Loader class just to run MyClass.java. However in the example their code ran without having to include a main method in Loader. Maybe they have customized their environment to allow for this type coding and IntelliJ just has different rules. Please could someone copy the code on their machines and run it with IntelliJ to see if they run into the same problem?

I've troubleshooted, but the code seems to be solid.

Comment: What is the error you are getting.

Comment: If you don't have a main, where did you call obj.start()? Also with java you need a main as your entry point.

Comment: Works on my machine :-)

Comment: Even if you remove the main method from Loader class it is working fine as expected and prints Hello Young World

Comment: Not related to your problem, but it is better to not extend `Thread`, and instead implement `Runnable` and pass an instant of that runnable to a `Thread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the program in my console I had to 'java MyClass' rather than running 'java MyClass.java' which executed the whole file rather than just the class whose main method I wanted to call!

To run the program in IntelliJ I had to make sure that the right Class was being called as pointed out above.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you start the wrong `main`-method (the main from the `Loader` class which is empty). As you noted, you don´t have to add a `main`-method in your `Loader` class. Please remove the method and start the `main`-method from `MyClass`.

If you have several main-methods, you can choose which one should be executed in the run configurations. In your example, it should look like this:

[image: run configurations]

In this case, make sure you select the one you like to execute.

Another way to execute the right main-method, is to select the class which contains the main-method and hit the play button on the left side:

[image]

Comment: I tried to do this however within IntelliJ i'm getting the error: Error: Could not find or load main class MyClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyClass

Comment: Thank you, to run the program in my  console I had to `java MyClass` rather than runningL `java MyClass.java` which executed the whole file rather than just the class whose main method I wanted to call!